# How can I delete files with one extension for corresponding files with some other extension, using Ant?

Tags: ant

Using Ant, I would like to clean a directory of all files having the extension '.dcu' for which a file exists that has the same basename with the extension '.pas'.

I cannot simply delete all '.dcu' files - some of them cannot be restored by compiling from source, because there is no corresponding '.pas' file.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this using a `fileset` with a [glob `mapper`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html) and the [`present` selector](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html#presentselect), for example:

```
<delete>
    <fileset dir="." includes="*.dcu">
        <present targetdir=".">
            <mapper type="glob" from="*.dcu" to="*.pas" />
        </present>
    </fileset>
</delete>
```